# How to assert if all buttons which I can see are in capital?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way in Selenium Webdriver using java to assert the all buttons that I can see are in upper case?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? This is not a code for hire site.

Comment: haven't tried it yet as our link is down for some reason. Eager to try and see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

basically there is a way, yes, you could do it as follows:

```
final WebDriver driver = getYourDriver();
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.name("button"));
for (WebElement button : buttons) {
    assertEquals(button.getText().toUpperCase(), button.getText());
}
```

But there is a limitation: This approach will only work if the buttons are  "really" in upper case. It will fail on the other hand, if the button text's are tranformed to upper case via css:

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

In this case, you would have to check the css applied to the buttons.

hope this helps.